# GLMM not working if I specify the distribution as gamma

Tags: generalized-linear-model, nonparametric

Following is the histogram and Q-Q plot of deceleration data retrieved from driving simulator experiment. As the data is not normally distributed, I am using generalized linear mixed model to analyze the impact of gender and age on the deceleration rate. but the analysis is not working if I specify the distribution type as gamma, it is working only if I specify the data as normal. In that case, which distribution I should specify in GLMM?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Again: please read our [help].  In particular, do not post a new question in order to clarify a previous post: just edit the original.  As far as this version goes, the distribution of your response variable is not directly relevant to the question.  What matters is the distribution *conditional on* the explanatory variables.  The distribution of the response reflects a combination of those conditional distributions and the distributions of the explanatory variables in your data.  It's best, then, to begin with a *multivariate* visualization, such as a scatterplot matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have categorical explanatory variables. So, their scatterplots are just stack of dots in a straight line. I am trying to figure out what should be the distribution type, if non-normal continuous data is analyzed using GLMMs?

Comment: Then use an alternative to scatterplots -- there are many, including boxplots, jittering the data, and much more.  Usually the shape of the conditional response is determined by the nature of the response itself and your theories about it.